# How can I return multiple rows in AsyncPG?

Tags: python, sql, asyncpg

Let's say I have a table with the following format:

| favoritefood | favoritedrink |
| --- | --- |
| pizza | water |
| ice cream | orange juice |
| pizza | milk |

How would I return both rows with `pizza` as the favorite food with Python?

I have `fetchrow` implemented for other functions, but it only works for one row, of course.

Ideally, they would be sorted into dictionaries (ex: `{favoritefood: pizza, favoritedrink: water`)

Comment: [fetchmany](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchmany) for pagination or [fetchall](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchall) for small resultset?

Comment: neither work with asyncpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To obtain multiple rows, use [fetch()](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#asyncpg.connection.Connection.fetch).

The returned `Record` instances are already `dict`-like, but if you really want regular Python dicts, simply convert the result data afterward:

```py
rows = await connection.fetch("SELECT * FROM table WHERE favoritefood = $1", 'pizza')
data = [dict(row) for row in rows]
```